# R ggplot2 getting "Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get na error

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:Average, Average, Average
```

trying to put a vertical line in a picture with multiple horizontal boxplots

Here is a piece of the data.frame gs1_domain, to draw boxplots is

[image]

and here is the data.frame R_18, to put the vertical lines in the plots

[image]

Below is my code that draw the boxplots

```
bp_domain <- ggplot(gs1_domain, aes(x=gs1_domain$Domain, y=gs1_domain$Average))
bp_domain + stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar') + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 1) + 
  coord_flip() + xlab("Domínio") + ylab("Média") + ggtitle("Box plot das médias por domínios")
```

With this code I get the following graph

[image]

I'm trying to put vertical lines in each boxplot, with data from the column `Average` in data.frame `R_18`.

Now, following some [google pages](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Lines_%28ggplot2%29/) I added to the code above the function geom_errorbar, and the new code is

```
bp_domain_R_18 <- ggplot(gs1_domain, aes(x=gs1_domain$Domain, y=gs1_domain$Average))
bp_domain_R_18 + stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar') + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(data=R_18, aes(y=Average, ymax=Average, ymin=Average)) +
  coord_flip() + xlab("Domínio") + ylab("Média") + ggtitle("Box plot das médias por domínios")
```

but I get that error message.
I already removed NA's from `gs1_domain`.

Someone can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Don't show a picture of your data, instead use `dput` to include (some) data in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
aes(x=gs1_domain$Domain, y=gs1_domain$Average)
```

with

```
aes(x=Domain, y=Average)
```

the dataframe is already specified, we only need to specify the column names within `aes`